# Generalized differences of powers

Tags: real-analysis

The binomial theorem allows one to expand $(x+y)^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as a finite sum. More generally, the generalized binomial theorem then allows one to expand $(x+y)^r$ for $r\in\mathbb{N}$ as a infinite sum.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can factorize 
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)\sum_{j=1}^{n}{x^{n-j}y^{j-1}}.$$
For $r\in\mathbb{R}$, can one find an analogous expression for $x^r-y^r$, presumably as the product of $(x-y)$ and some infinite sum?

I can get a result somewhat like this when $r=1/2$ but the general case eludes me.

Comment: You probably want to use the gamma function for binomial coefficients: 
$$(^x_y)= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-y+1)\Gamma(y+1)}$$

Comment: What's the result when $r=\frac12$?

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but I rewrote the expression as $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$ and then expended the denominator using a geometric series. But nonetheless, you have clearly indicated below why I can't expect anything better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analogous result is not to be expected because when $r$ is not a positive integer, $x^r$ is not analytic at $0$.  The generalized binomial theorem expresses $(x+y)^r$ as an analytic function of $x$, or of $y$, in a neighborhood of $0$, if the other variable is nonzero and fixed.   To have a result of the form $x^r-y^r=(x-y)\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x) y^k$ with $y$ sufficiently small would imply that $y\mapsto y^r$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$, which it isn't unless $r$ is in $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but assuming $0 < y < x$, we have
$$ \frac{x^r - y^r}{x - y} = \frac{x^r - y^r}{x} \frac{1}{1 - y/x} = \frac{x^r - y^r}{x}[1 + (y/x) + (y/x)^2 + \dots]$$

You get a different sum if instead $0 < x < y$. When $r$ is a positive inetger, all but finitely many of the terms cancel and you get the sum you wrote.